# How can I get the Kendo upload control to reauthenticate in IE.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, upload, kendo-ui

I have a form with a kendo upload control and a save button along with a kendo grid.  When I open the form using Chrome or Firefox, the upload control works every time.  When I open the form in Internet Explorer 10 and leave the form open for more than 1 minute without doing anything, the upload stops working.

I am working on an ASP.net MVC 4 web application.

In Fiddler I see 2 entries.

```
**POST /PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/ProcessSubmit HTTP/1.1**
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd36d1cb0ce0
Referer: http://localhost:82/PRODUCT/Admin/?contentUrl=/PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/Page?cbuId=42aff2e4-33bb-4f73-8500-596f6d73ce3a
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:82
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: .MVCRETURNURL=/PRODUCT/Areas/FOLDER/Views/FOLDER2/Page.cshtml; .MVCAUTH=; .ASPXAUTH=F39BF9AA8D958D1783D6A939F3A6B499B81089434C09AC65C168BEF1E298B480935446E77B12A2044F4A7622C82B91DE7C1C6D8E09C4408A9D7C519E6EBB7ACD481735D851AA1A9E65A05CE34AFAE77FCB5E86DDD2EA2F05988C36BEBF5B30994ACEE33557FF3027D875A14ADE2128D2C9C8F20E
Authorization: Negotiate YHcGBisGAQUFAqBtMGugMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI3BDVOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBQAFADAAAAAIAAgAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPQ0tEUDA1MTRFQUVEMQ==
Content-Length: 0


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYIBHDCCARigAwoBAaEMBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKooIBAQSB/k5UTE1TU1AAAgAAAAoACgA4AAAAFcKJ4tPeOOS7ZmVeEKH7AQAAAAC8ALwAQgAAAAYBsR0AAAAPRQBBAEUARAAxAAIACgBFAEEARQBEADEAAQAQAEMASwBEAFAAMAA1ADEANAAEACQAcABlAHQAcgBvAGwAZQB1AG0AcABsAGEAYwBlAC4AYwBvAG0AAwA2AEMASwBEAFAAMAA1ADEANAAuAHAAZQB0AHIAbwBsAGUAdQBtAHAAbABhAGMAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAUAJABwAGUAdAByAG8AbABlAHUAbQBwAGwAYQBjAGUALgBjAG8AbQAHAAgAiqpF+oprzgEAAAAA
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 18:46:28 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Authorized</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Authorized</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

------------------------------------------------------------------
**POST /PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/ProcessSubmit HTTP/1.1**
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd36d1cb0ce0
Referer: http://localhost:82/PRODUCT/Admin/?contentUrl=/PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/Page?cbuId=42aff2e4-33bb-4f73-8500-596f6d73ce3a
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 12435
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:82
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: .MVCRETURNURL=/PRODUCT/Areas/FOLDER/Views/FOLDER2/Page.cshtml; .MVCAUTH=; .ASPXAUTH=F39BF9AA8D958D1783D6A939F3A6B499B81089434C09AC65C168BEF1E298B480935446E77B12A2044F4A7622C82B91DE7C1C6D8E09C4408A9D7C519E6EBB7ACD481735D851AA1A9E65A05CE34AFAE77FCB5E86DDD2EA2F05988C36BEBF5B30994ACEE33557FF3027D875A14ADE2128D2C9C8F20E
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UTE1TU1AAAwAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAABXCiOIGAbEdAAAADwjVcbbDNKZpdbLdjWcqj76jEgQQAQAAAPUXp1AtIpqEAAAAAA==


    ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I press the save button on the same page, I see almost identical fiddler entries.

```
POST /PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/UpdateMajorCodes HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:82/PRODUCT/Admin/?contentUrl=/PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/Page?cbuId=42aff2e4-33bb-4f73-8500-596f6d73ce3a
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: localhost:82
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: .MVCRETURNURL=/PRODUCT/; .MVCAUTH=; .ASPXAUTH=9079B8150CB469C41BA155173534C32ABF863F0369000D0DCE3DB0A2AFF6124AB0878537E11EC70C59B118F8957B657E1E0D6D9C4233F39D2435040ADAFF397EEF703D4535AAA153753A4888BB6FF4DD053A303FA65C506ECB2F2F01A17E1A27F9C9EA2D468F5E77BD2F971698427989BB5372E7
Authorization: Negotiate YHcGBisGAQUFAqBtMGugMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI3BDVOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBQAFADAAAAAIAAgAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPQ0tEUDA1MTRFQUVEMQ==


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYIBHDCCARigAwoBAaEMBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKooIBAQSB/k5UTE1TU1AAAgAAAAoACgA4AAAAFcKJ4pCCkvtzwTQ5oJ/7AQAAAAC8ALwAQgAAAAYBsR0AAAAPRQBBAEUARAAxAAIACgBFAEEARQBEADEAAQAQAEMASwBEAFAAMAA1ADEANAAEACQAcABlAHQAcgBvAGwAZQB1AG0AcABsAGEAYwBlAC4AYwBvAG0AAwA2AEMASwBEAFAAMAA1ADEANAAuAHAAZQB0AHIAbwBsAGUAdQBtAHAAbABhAGMAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAUAJABwAGUAdAByAG8AbABlAHUAbQBwAGwAYQBjAGUALgBjAG8AbQAHAAgA6r5c6ZdrzgEAAAAA
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 20:19:03 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Authorized</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Authorized</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

------------------------------------------------------------------
POST /PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/UpdateMajorCodes HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:82/PRODUCT/Admin/?contentUrl=/PRODUCT/FOLDER/FOLDER2/Page?cbuId=42aff2e4-33bb-4f73-8500-596f6d73ce3a
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: localhost:82
Content-Length: 13798
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: .MVCRETURNURL=/PRODUCT/; .MVCAUTH=; .ASPXAUTH=9079B8150CB469C41BA155173534C32ABF863F0369000D0DCE3DB0A2AFF6124AB0878537E11EC70C59B118F8957B657E1E0D6D9C4233F39D2435040ADAFF397EEF703D4535AAA153753A4888BB6FF4DD053A303FA65C506ECB2F2F01A17E1A27F9C9EA2D468F5E77BD2F971698427989BB5372E7
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UTE1TU1AAAwAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAABXCiOIGAbEdAAAAD93bE7wOkB2UOLRe3+N5TJ6jEgQQAQAAAPUXp1AtIpqEAAAAAA==
```

The save works and makes a call in to the server to save the data.  The upload server call never happens.  I am trying to figure out how to get the upload to work in IE 10 after the authentication timeout.

thanks
Kent Pigott